# How do I include Postscript graphics in a LaTeX file?

Tags: graphics, pdftex, include, postscript

I am trying to include `sample.ps` file to my document with the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{psbox}

\begin{document}

\PSbox{sample.ps}{4in}{6in}

\end{document}
```

But it is failing. Is it possible to include .ps file to our latex document?
Is there any method like  `\includepdf[pages=-]{my_file.pdf}` ?

Comment: I think you have to use something other than `pdftex`. See here: http://www.math.mun.ca/~edgar/includeps.html

Comment: Is is your ps file multipage? If not things should be straight forward as inclusion of a graphics file.

Comment: @JohnWickerson I tried that method, but still failing

Comment: @Masroor my file is a single page ps file

Comment: @RSJohn When you say that the method at http://www.math.mun.ca/~edgar/includeps.html is failing, what exactly is the error message? Simply saying "failing" does not provide much helpful information.

Comment: What about converting the `ps` file to a `pdf` file (e.g., using `ps2pdf`) and then include the resulting `pdf`?

Comment: Can you make the ps file available somewhere?

Comment: @Guido we can do it. But I want to know a method to including ps.

Comment: @HarishKumar sir here is my [sample.ps](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6l5iRWTUbHWMk5TS2RscXpHUDQ/edit)

Comment: @RSJohn Looking at the file, it's an EPS (there is a bounding box). Changing the extension to `.eps`, using `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphics}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{sample}
\end{document}` works for me with both DVI and PDF output modes.

Comment: @Johannes_B sample.ps is not created with tex. It is plotted with python plotting library matplotlib. If I add \arcsec in my tex document, it is giving me the following error                                                                                                `Undefined control sequence.`
`l.84 $ \arcsec`

Comment: You can use `\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}` and then it will work. I don't have `psbox` installed so can't check with your code. But: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=4in]{sample.ps}

\end{document}` works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Trying the solution suggested by @user11232, it does work. Since that user is no longer available, and with the desire to respond this unanswered question, it is important to have it solved for future references in the site.

The PDF output was generated with `LaTeX-->PS-->PDF` in TeXnicCenter, by taking the [`sample.ps` image](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6l5iRWTUbHWMk5TS2RscXpHUDQ/edit) provided by OP in comments

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm,a4paper]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm} 
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} 

\begin{document} 

\includegraphics[width=4in]{sample.ps} 

\end{document}
```

> [image]