# How do I fix Package pdftex.def Error with overleaf?

Tags: compiling, postscript

I'm trying to include a ps file with this code adapted from another tex.stackexchange [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/404803/192089)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm,a4paper]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm} 
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} 
\begin{document} 
\includegraphics[width=4in]{support.vector.ps} 
\end{document}
```

with overleaf I got this error

> Package pdftex.def Error: File `output-pics.pdf' not found: using draft setting.

[image]

[Here](https://www.overleaf.com/read/fmjngrvknthk) is all the content of it.

How do I fix this error?

Comment: pdftex can't input ps files so it is trying to convert on the fly it would be simpler if you uploaded the image as pdf, or try renaming it to .eps rather than .ps  also try without auto-pst-pdf unless you need pstricks for other reasons

Answer (score 3):

Renaming the PostScript file to `support.vector.eps` and commenting off `\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}` seem to fix the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm,a4paper]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm} 
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
%\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} 
\begin{document} 
\includegraphics[width=4in]{support.vector.eps} 
\end{document}
```

[image]